# Bind xml to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I am stumped. 
I have the following XML, I think it was taken from another StackOverflow question in fact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HousingShapes>
<Shape Name="Rectangular" id="1/3"/>
<Shape Name="Circular" id="1/34" />
<Shape Name="Triangular" id="1/23" />
<Shape Name="Other Shape" id="1/15" />
</HousingShapes>
```

I have bound my data like this in XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" Source="d:\people.xml" XPath="HousingShapes"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And my ComboBox below

```
  <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,52,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, XPath=./Shape}" DisplayMemberPath="@Name" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, XPath=./Shape}" SelectedValue="@id" />
```

I want the user to see 'Shape Name' i.e Rectangular in the combobox. This bit works. But I want the id to be used when adding the data. as a test, I wrote the following

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValuePath);
    }
```

Expecting to see 1/3 when Rectangular was selected or 1/15 when 'Other Shape' was selected, but nothing.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems here, first you need to set the `SelectedValuePath` to @id

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" Source="C:\people.xml" XPath="HousingShapes/Shape"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}}" DisplayMemberPath="@Name" SelectedValuePath="@id" />
    </Grid>
```

second the MessageBox is showing the `SelectedValuePath`, it should be the `Selectedvalue`

```
 MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

`Selectedvalue` returns the value defined in `SelectedValuePath`

Comment: Thank you. I have been searching the Internet for 2 days now looking for this solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox ... DisplayMemberPath="@Name" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, XPath=./Shape}" SelectedValue="@id" />
```

Should be:

```
DisplayMemberPath="@Name" SelectedValuePath="@id"
```

with no `SelectedValue` set. You were on the right path, just got the attributes mixed up a little. :)

Comment: Thank you Steve. I did try that previously. But my message box displays @id. Is there anything I did to change in the MessageBox.Show statement to display the id's as 1/15, etc. Thank you for your help